# Cannot find sbt silent installation document

Tags: scala, sbt, silent-installer

I am trying to find the silent installation of sbt,
unfortunately I could not.

Could anyone help and share it with me please?
Thanx in advance

Comment: What is a silent installation? What is the use case you want to solve?

Comment: I am trying to install sbt but in silent way. I can not find any document regarding the silent installation from the vendor.. so I am seeking for your help please